# Prestashop default bootstrap theme was deleted

Tags: prestashop

Prestashop default bootstrap theme was deleted,how to call it back in the system where i can find the default theme listing with other themes ? Please help.

Comment: Ok I have found a solution for that,for its working.Lets see idf some one has any better idea.
1.Unzip the same version of prestashop.

Comment: Ok I have found a solution for that,for its working.Lets see idf some one has any better idea.

1.Unzip the same version of prestashop.
2.Go to the themes directory and copy the default-bootstrap folder and place it to the same location of your project file.
3.Now go to the database. Search for the table YOURPREFIX_theme table.Insert there with the name,directory,responsive,default-left-column(set it 1) and product_per_page( set it 12).
4.Click go

Go to your themes section in admin section,you will find the default theme here.

Answer (score 2):

If you have deleted the files physically you can only recover them from a backup.

If you have not done any change to default bootstrap theme, you can download your PrestaShop version from this page https://www.prestashop.com/en/previous-versions and upload folder `/themes/default-bootstrap` to `/themes`.

*For PS 1.6:*

Ensure that the themeis on database. Check table `ps_theme`. If it isn't execute this script:

```
INSERT INTO `ps_theme` (`name`, `directory`, `responsive`, `default_left_column`, `default_right_column`, `product_per_page`)
VALUES ('default-bootstrap', `default-bootstrap', '1', '1', '0', '12');
```